# what is the best way to write to a file in java uncontinuously?

Tags: java, android, io, android-file, android-bluetooth

I'm programming an android app that transfers a file over bluetooth.

My question is, what is the best way to write a file uncontinuously, meaning the file is being written in the external storage directory while the data is sent in chunks via bluetooth. 
the writing obviously occurs faster and takes pauses between receiving two chunks.

Are RandomAccessFile and FileChannel efficient for that task?

Thanks in advance.

P.S:
file size is about 10MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you go to utilize `RandomAccessFile`, so beware about the flushing mechanism, its not manual, and it may give some time(specially when you write data small). my suggestion is `FileChanel`, you would take control of flushing, of course it doesn't support direct functionality for writing primitive data, but you would utilize `ByteBuffer` to doing so.

Comment: it dependents buddy, so how are you going to read and write data?! if it's just like read a buffer and write it so, so don't be worry, but if there is some data manipulation with primitive data, so you may need to utilize the `ByteBuffer` class, also take care about the seeking and writing, because it OVERRIDES/extends from the position.

Answer (score 1):

Why random access? Are you going to write in the middle of the file? If not than a simple file appender will do. And you don't need to keep your file open all the time...